# CodeIgniter : error 403 after submit form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I try to send my form with the `base_url()` method (so I click on the submit button), instead of the result of my request, I have a 403 error on the other page (forbidden acces), on the page generated by my controller.

I use a Wampp Server, the version 3.1.8 of CodeIgniter. I've also add `url` in the autoload file.

I have `.htacess` file with that :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

View page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="<? echo base_url();?>form_validation">
        <label> Name </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: This needs more context to be answerable.

Comment: have you loaded url helper in autoload or in contoller

Comment: Yes : https://framapic.org/x1BI8H2lFvCF/ic8eYKBzntRb.PNG

Comment: ok set ur base_url in config.php if not if yes pls show and also validation controller method

Comment: base_url : https://framapic.org/Jpz6QqIUUuYu/7sYYq2xJr0N1.PNG
In the validation controller, I try to show something (even if it's not the right way to do in MVC, it's just to test if it works) : https://framapic.org/yJ5haTMvSkvX/uIwLnjRdjfCa.PNG

Comment: In controller :  you have method `form_validation`  and you given in form action only `validation` may be this is just a typo

Comment: I diid a mistake but in my code, I have form_validation on the two files. When there is no controller with that name, there is a 404 error

Comment: Please add the snipped for the controller method being hit.  You may also want to place a `die` statement in there, test, and repeat until its output is no longer visible to narrow in on the problem.  You said your controller is throwing back the error, so unless that's a typo, it means your .htaccess config isn't the problem.

Comment: But I haven't this error when a write the complete URL (localhost...) on the action of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

NOTE : **Assuming that default controller is `welcome`** in `route.php` if not replace welcome with yours

*In controller :  you have method `form_validation`  and you give in form action only `validation` :*

```
public function form_validation()
{
   echo 'OK';
}
```

Your form view is just like this :

**REPLACE** :

```
/* note missing php error in action*/

<form method="post" action="<? echo base_url();?>form_validation">
```

**With** :

```
/*add controller name also in action, 
  assuming your default controller is Welcome*/

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('welcome/form_validation');?>">
```

View should be like this :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('welcome/form_validation');?>">
     <label> Name </label>
     <input type="text" name="name" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

`route.php` should be like this :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**NOTE ALSO** :  *.`htaccess` should be in project folder , in your case CI folder*

Comment: see my answer and correct yours as according, by the way what is your controller name

Comment: it will surely sort out your problem just do as it is in my answer

Comment: It works, thanks :).
Could you explain me why ?
And what I should do if I want to send the view on an other controller than the default controller ? I just have to replace welcome by the controller name ?

Comment: just create the the controller and a method in it , and pass it in form action with controller name and method